# Why form return error "inactive user" in generic.View

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-login

I am writing a site on Django and faced the problem that when users are authorized, the form returns the error "This user account is inactive" in any case. Although I did this before and everything was fine

***This is my views.py file:***

```
    template_name = 'users_logic/user_login.html'
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('main_page')

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class
        return render(request, 'users_logic/user_login.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password,
                                backend=settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND)
            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                print(user)
                messages.success(request, 'Ви успішно авторизувались')
                return redirect('main_page')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Помилка авторизації')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Неправильний логін або пароль')
            print(form.error_messages)
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, 'users_logic/user_login.html', {'form': form})
```

***this is my register view:***

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'users_logic/user_register.html'
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_login')
    success_message = "Реєстрація пройшла успішно"
```

***my login_form:***

```
class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user_form
        fields = ('username', 'password1')

    username = forms.CharField(label='Ваш логін',
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label='Ваш пароль',
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the django User model provides a property called `is_active`. This prop is set as False by default when you create a new user.
You have to manually set the user active, or if you are using the default implementation, you can enable a user registration by email link or other...

Some documentations:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active
https://www.javatpoint.com/django-user-registration-with-email-confirmation

For your case, you can probably for beginning, just add the is_active prop in the save of your `UserRegisterForm` form

```py
class UserRegisterForm(...):

    [...]

    def save(self, sommit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)

        instance.is_active = True

        if commit:
            instance.save()
    
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in your forms.py

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'users_logic/user_register.html'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_login')
    success_message = "Реєстрація пройшла успішно"
```

The UserCreationForm uses default User's model manager to set is_active to True